# How to count how many elements in array smaller than last number

Tags: c++, arrays

I tried to write a program which that i can detect **how many elements/members in array is smaller than last elements in array.**
i have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

float number[10];
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
    cout << "Please enter numbers: ";
    cin >> number[10];
}
if (number[10] >= number)
{
    // Some code
}

_getch();
return 0;
}
```

but this is incorrect. how can i do that ?

Comment: Side note: `i <= 10` will attempt to access `number[10]` which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: what do you mean with "incorrect"? The part doing the counting is completely missing....

Comment: I am assuming you mean last element of array? Not elements, therefore you're comparing all elements to the tenth number correct? If this is true what do you expect to happen if and if not smaller? Since you have an `if` statement. Also are you comparing the tenth element to itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can add another for loop to iterate over the array and check each item.

```
int count = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
   if(number[i] < number[9])
     count++;
```

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to read array in wrong way :

```
float number[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << "Please enter numbers: ";
    cin >> number[i];
}
```

to find how many elements smaller than last element :

```
float min = number[9];
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
     if( number[i] < min ){
         count++
     }          
}
cout << count << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You read wrong the array. You have to use `cin>>number[i]`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   cout << "Please enter numbers: ";
   cin >> number[i];
}
```

Also, you read `11` elements, and you have declared array as `number[10]`. Change to `number[9]`.

To find `minimum`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
   cout << "Please enter numbers: ";
   cin >> number[i];
}
float min = number[9];
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
   if( number[i] < min ){
     count++;
   }          
}
```

Comment: for loop condition should be i < 10 because he has only 10 elements in array

Comment: he define array size float number[10]; 

so it will not work in your for loop condition

Comment: His loop entry for `11` times.And he must to declare number[11]

Comment: I know but size of his array only holds 10 elements